# Arduino C/C++ progamming tutorials

Tags: arduino

I have no problem in reading circuit schemes, connecting wires, resistors etc. (basing on for example instructables.com), but I've only tried to learn Java (a while ago) and it's difficult to me to find out what's going on with all this C-code-stuff.
Are there any tutorials that are focused on the programming part?
thanks

Comment: This will be an unpopular post, but I'd highly recommend you try to learn C with a basic microcontroller, not Arudino, unless you don't really care to understand what is really going on. With Arduino, you are limited by a few things that you really won't understand at this point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, basically, you recommend buying for example Atmega32? Is it much harder to learn?

Comment: I would recommend any of the ATmega or ATtiny products that are through hole with an ISP interface, popular ones are ATmega328, ATtiny25, ATtiny24, or ATtiny2313. They also come in models with more program space, for example, ATtiny84 has 8kBytes of flash, while the ATtiny24 only has 2kBytes. Programming them in C is common for beginners, and it is not hard if you are familiar at all with C statements like if/else, for loops, etc. The new thing to learn with microcontrollers is to involve the dedicated hardware: interrupts, SPI, TWI interface, etc which is all found in the product datasheet.

Comment: You will need an ISP programmer like this: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9825 which can be used on ALL of your projects, unlike Arduino which is built into the board, hence, you'd have to buy a new board for each new project. Also, look into getting the essentials such as a breadboard, jumper wire, 1k and 10k resistors, .1uF ceramic caps, and a few push buttons. These are all pretty cheap parts that will be used on every circuit you build with an MCU. I'm working on putting a tutorial together, but for now, Google search for getting started with AVR.

Comment: Thanks! I bought usbasp programmer and other stuff, I also found AVR Hardware/C for AVR tutorial. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 A great way to learn C/C++ for arduino is by going to the website: ardx.org/CIRC01
```

This website is completely and gives great mini projects that involve electronics and then gives an example code and a great explanation of how the code works. This site consists of 11 projects and explains the basics of C/C++ for arduino, it also teaches you how to read schematics and data sheets. After you are done with project #1 change the CIRC01 at the end of url to CIRC02, and each time you complete a project continue to go to the next one by changing the # on the end of the CIRC to a higher # until you get to 11. By the time you get to project #11 you should have a good understanding of programming for arduino and a better understanding of electronics as well. Another way that I learned C++ is by reading the book "C++ for Dummies by Stephen R. Davis". This book teaches C++ in a simple yet affective fashion, however it is quite tedious to completely read this book, if it were me I would start by using the projects on ardx.org and then once I have finished all the projects and if I wanted even more knowledge on programming c/C++ then read the book. Good luck!

Comment: Also as DaemonMaker said, thelearning section does offer a good amount at programming arduino, if you ever have a question about a variable or something of the like, then under the learning section of arduino is a "reference" page, under this section arduino does a GREAT job of listing variable types, arrays, and all sorts of stuff that you might need to use, simply find what you are looking for and click the link, it will bring up a nice page all about it.

Comment: Thanks! I've already found "thinking in c++" ebook and I will start learning C++ separately. ardx.org looks great!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, under the [learning](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HomePage) section of the [Arduino website](http://arduino.cc) there are a number of coding tutorials. They begin with explaining the [minimum code necessary](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BareMinimum) to how to use many of the peripherals. These tutorials explain fairly well what each line of the programs do.